# Cannot seed MongoDB with models

Tags: mongodb, casting

I am a beginner in MongoDB and try to cast a model into another one. I first seed both models and then I try to cast one into the other. The problem is it doesnt work the products are not inserted into market. I cannot find the error though...

```
function connectDataModels(){

    Market.find({},function(error,markets){

            if(error){
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
            else {

                    markets.forEach(function(market){

                        Product.find({},function(error,products){

                                if(error){
                                    console.log("ERROR");
                                }
                                else{

                                        products.forEach(function(product){

                                                    market.products.push(product);
                                                    market.save();

                                        });

                                }

                        });

                });

            }

    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Stefano, is the goal to have an array of all the products in the products collection on every market in the markets collection?

Comment: I Mark - no actually not! I just try to create an array of products for every market. I should be easy? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you able to add some sample data?